# Get range in sorted std::vector satisfying to some condition

Tags: c++, std

I have a sorted `std::vector`. Now I need to get range of items that satisfy to some condition. E.g.

```
vector -> 1, 4, 25, 73 450
get range that is smaller then 100 -> {1, 4, 25, 73}
```

How can I do this using std?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use standard algorithm `std::lower_bound`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{   
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 4, 25, 73, 450 };

    auto last = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 100 );

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != last; ++it ) std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 4 25 73
```

If to substitute statement

```
auto last = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 100 );
```

for

```
auto last = std::lower_bound( v.begin(), v.end(), 50 );
```

then the output will be

```
1 4 25
```

And so on.:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [std::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range). Simply define your predicate in a correct manner. Please note that the example condition you give meets the criteria for equal_range but for other conditions you may not be able to use std::equal_range.

Here is an example predicate for the given example:

```
bool smaller(int a, int b) {
  return (a < 100) > (b < 100);
}
```

Here I consider two numbers equal if they compare to 100 the same way. If they do not a number smaller than 100 is smaller than a number not less than 100. Now you can call:

```
equal_range(a.begin(), a.end(), 50 /* any number < 100 */, smaller);
```

Comment: `std::equal_range` requires that the elements be sorted, and can only return a range; I don't see how it can be made to work with an arbitrary condition.

Comment: @JamesKanze I already mentioned it can not be made to work with just any condition but will work for the given example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `remove_if` or `remove_if_copy` is what you're looking for, e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> results;
std::remove_copy_if( original.cbegin(), original.cend(), std::back_inserter( results ),
                     []( int value ) { return value < 100; } );
```

Put whatever you need in the lambda for the actual problem.  (In pre C++11, you'll have to define a functional object with the predicate outside the function which calls `remove_copy_if`, but otherwise, the principle is the same.)